# How can I send a Wake on Wireless LAN (WoWLAN) / Wake on Demand request manually?

Tags: linux, mac-osx

This is similar to, but not the same as, [Is wireless wake on lan possible?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1721/is-wireless-wake-on-lan-possible). I *know* it is supposed to be possible. The question is, how do I do whatever the AirPort Basestation will do?

All I can find so far is that supposedly I need to send something with Wireless Multimedia Extensions (WMM):

Basically, I want to be able to wake up my Mac Mini remotely, probably using my Linux laptop. Does anyone know of a tool to do this? Basic Wake on LAN tools do not seem to be the right thing. I don't need the Sleep Proxy Service bit, because I already know the MAC address of the system I want to wake up.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this before with a [python script that I found on the intarwebs](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/358449-wake-on-lan/). With this script, you'd simply put your MAC in at the bottom and you should be good to go.

Comment: That's just for Wake on LAN. I've already found a zillion tools for that, and that does not work, unfortunately. I think this requires something that works at the level of the wireless interface, not at the IP level.

Comment: just use the tool jed daniels gave you, it will work. configure your mac like this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774   BTW: jeds py script doesnt work on the IP level, it works one level below (ARP).